# Log users back in after server side update. .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, .net-core-3.1

I am racking my brain to solve this problem and I am hoping someone can steer me the right direction.

Scenario:

Users are logged into a .NET Core 3.1 application using a basic

```
HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, authProperties);
```

method.

Development takes the server offline using app_offline.htm and updates the DLLs (offline for seconds at most). All users lose their session and will get 401 codes until they log back in.

Is there a way to log the users back after the server side update without the users aware of the fact?

Answer (score 0):

OK so after researching this more I learned that every time an application is restarted a new "machine key" is generated, thus making any user authentication cookie invalid/unauthorized. The answer is to set a static machine key in your applications web.config file.

```
<system.web>
  <machine validationKey="KEYHERE" 
    decryptionKey="KEYHERE" 
    validation="SHA1" 
    decryption="AES" />
</system.web>
```

There is a site that will generate random keys for you here: https://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/ASP-Net-MachineKey-Generator.aspx

There isn't an option for .NET Core on there but I used the .NET 4.5 and it works just fine on a .NET Core 3.1 application.

Next you need to add the following code to your `Startup.cs` file.

```
var keysFolder = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "Keys");

services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keysFolder))
    .SetApplicationName("MoverasKanBan")
    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(90));
```

The variable `_environment` was injected into the `Startup.cs` constructor like this:

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
    _environment = environment;
}
```

Also don't forget to actually create the directory "Keys" in the root of your application and make sure that your app pool has permission to read/write to that folder.

Users sessions will now be valid even after the application is restarted, since the machine key is static.

Comment: Have you considered the security implications?

Comment: Yes, the application has additional layers of security, and is an internal application, not on the net. I wouldn’t do this on a public application.

Comment: With that being said if you know of an alternative to this solution let me know.